# Cannot access properties or methods for the Microsoft.SqlServer.Mangement.Smo.Agent.JobStep

Tags: c#, .net, smo, sql-server-agent

I am accessing SQL Server Agent Job from C# application using SMO.
The Job runs fine in SQL Server Agent but errors out when run from C# randomly
with the error

> Cannot access properties or methods for the
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Mangement.Smo.Agent.JobStep

This error occurs during Job step refresh.

Comment: Is the mdf file attached to a server or are you using localdb.  If you have multiple users accessing the database it has to be attached to a server.  DO NOT USER LOCAL DB in connection string when attached to a server.  LOCALDB is only meant to be used when the mdf file is not attached to server.